# Searching is not responsive during indexing with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

When I re-index the DB data of my application, and there is a search executed on the same time, the thread that runs the search is going to sleep until the re-indexing is done. I assume that the indexing methods are thread-safe in order to prevent change of the data while indexing. Is there any built in way in Lucene to make it responsive only for search (where the data is not being changed)? Or should I start thinking about something on my own? I'm running my application on a Tomcat server.

Thanks, Tomer

Comment: There should be no problem in writing and reading to the index simultaneously. The readers will only see committed data (unless you're using near-real-time searches). What you describe should work. Could you give us example code that experience this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are actually *rebuilding* the index (or reindexing everything from scratch, as opposed to reindexing individual documents). While the index is being rebuilt, you cannot perform the queries against it, because it's not in consistent state.

The simplest solution that is often used is to rebuild the index in the background (while still performing the queries against the old one) and then replace it with the fresh one.

If the problem you are facing is connected with frequent server crashes, it might be worthwhile to look at some more systematical approach like the one that is implemented for example in [Zoie](http://sna-projects.com/zoie/) -- it records subsequent indexing requests, so it can recover from the last correct snapshot of the index.

Comment: Is there any built in "Copy on write" mechanism in Lucene for that?

Comment: I don't know of any such mechanism in Lucene itself. Managing of the indexes is passed to the application or search server (Solr/ES). I think that for example [Solr's multicores support](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) can be used for that.